# how to know loop duration in c#

Tags: c#, time

I search for method in c# which calculate duration of  a loop or any thing like that, think my program consists for or while "`for(...,...,...){}`" I need how much does time it take by the what is the type of method output

Comment: How come you can't write your own `StartTime-EndTime` `TimeSpan` calculation..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am afraid that wont calculate the EXACT time I need the time for performance

Comment: stopwatch is the best answer below.

Comment: I believe that you can get the exact time is you look at the `TimeSpan` example depicted in `Haedrian` answer.. the thing that you need to understand is the `TotalSeconds` part.. he could have gone even further and provide you a string.Format(hh:mm:ss)` example but at some point you will have to start thinking / experimenting with the code and it's possibilities on your own as well..

Comment: I find this after all suggestions http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Stopwatch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to
>   accurately measure elapsed time.

```
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    // stuff you want to time here...

    stopWatch.Stop();

    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

    // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the
>   underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating
>   system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the
>   Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise,
>   the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. Use
>   the **Frequency** and **IsHighResolution** fields to determine the precision
>   and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime startingTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

//Your loops go here

DateTime endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

Timespan timeDifference = endTime - startingTime;

double seconds = timeDifference.TotalSeconds;
```

There is also a Stopwatch class if you need even more precision than that

Comment: got me in a minute. best choice there is

Comment: is that bring time with milisecodns or less I know there is something like that in c++

Comment: let the `OP` know that in the TimeSpan line you have that the second use of the DateTime.utcNow` variable equates to `EndTime` there are many new as well as seasoned developers whom for get that total time is `EndTime - StartTime` in regards to creating a `TimeSpan` and not `StartTime - EndTime` ...

Comment: @DJKRAZE - you make a valid point. Done.